# Is it possible to obtain the value of a variable from the activity in the layout.xml android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to know if I can obtain a calculated number from my main activity and access it from my layout.xml.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    float margin_top = (1920f/height) * 125;
    String margin_top_str = Float.toString(margin_top) + "dp";
}
```

layout.xml code

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:id="button"
    android:background="#f57878"
    android:textSize="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@MainActivity.java/margin_top_str"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

The line `android:layout_marginTop="@MainActivity.java/margin_top_str"` is not real and is only to show what I need. If what I am asking can be done only in the activity that would work fine too. p.s. I am a noob. Thanks

Comment: why are you not setting the margin in the java code?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not. You can only reference constants and values from other XML resources but you can't reference java code.

Instead, calculate the value for different screen sizes and put to corresponding res folders in `dimens.xml`. If it can't be calculated then just set it in runtime through `MarginLayoutParams`.